# input onfocus not changing div style

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have two input forms. I want the second input form to appear when the user focuses on the first input form. I used a simple javascript "onfocus" within the input tags. This worked fine when it was changing the style of another input form. This however left an unwanted gap. I tried making it so the entire div group appeard onfocus but it had no effect.

I want to make the entire "form-group" div to appear when the user focuses on the first input form but for some reason, this is not working at all.

HTML

```
<div class="form-group<?php if(form_error('con_password') != ''){ echo " has-error"; } ?>">
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <input type="password" name="con_password" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Password Confirmation" onfocus="occupation.style.display='block'">
        <span class="help-block"><?php echo form_error('con_password'); ?></span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group<?php if(form_error('occupation') != ''){ echo " has-error"; } ?>" id="occupation">
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <input type="text" name="occupation" class="form-control input-lg" value="<?php echo set_value('occupation'); ?>" placeholder="Occupation" onfocus="hearus.style.display='block'">
        <span class="help-block"><?php echo form_error('occupation'); ?></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#occupation{
   display: none;   
}
```

Comment: Can you please set up a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: It works just fine for me. (Without all the PHP though).

Comment: It worked fine on JSFiddle which is why I was very confused. http://jsfiddle.net/ducg5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`onfocus="occupation.style.display='block'` should be `onfocus="document.getElementById('id').style.display=block"`

Comment: This worked, thank you. How come the first one worked when "occupation" was the id of an input?

Comment: put your code in jsfiddle so that we can debug more to find how come the first one worked for you. :)

Comment: This is what I had above (without the PHP). It works fine. http://jsfiddle.net/ducg5/

Comment: It's an effect of the habit of (some) browsers to make dom nodes available via the global object (window here), by their id - if the property is not used already   :(

Answer (score 0):

```
onfocus="document.getElementById('occupation').style.display='block'"
```

Answer (score 0):

In your handlers, the code does not know what "occupation" (for ex.) is. You need to get a reference to it, then manipulate its style.